# robots.txt like route in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp-2.0, robots.txt

I want something like this:

```
Router::connect('/robots.txt', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'robotstxt'));
```

But when I try: http://example.com/robots.txt it's show me 404.

Also I tried do this:

```
Router::connect('/robots', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'robotstxt', 'ext' => 'txt'));
+
Router::parseExtensions('txt');
```

Comment: Place the robots.txt on webroot... You don't need to map this to controller... And http://example.com/robots.txt will show robots.txt

Comment: I need different robots.txt for subdomains (wildcard).

Answer (score 0):

Leave the `ext` part - like as-

```
Router::connect('/robots', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'robotstxt'));
Router::parseExtensions('txt');
```

Comment: It should work.. Do you having any file robots.txt on webroot?? Don't forget to remove that...

Comment: No, I have't any robots.txt file on webroot.

Comment: Hm.. I tested on my local server that using apache and its works (even my solution)

Comment: Good to see... I have to mention 1 thing... `PagesController` works differently then normal controller... It will good if you map as- `Router::connect('/robots', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'robotstxt'));` and just create a `robotstxt.ctp` on `Pages View`...